# How to build a Javascript "roundabout" slider

Tags: javascript, slider, jquery-roundabout

I'm building a website and one of the sections has an interactive slider with x amount of images.

Rather than use a normal style slider I want to go for the "roundabout" effect, something along the lines of the following:

http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_36922/
http://www.joezimjs.com/demos/roundabout-demo/

Now I know I could just use these pre built plugins and i'm sure they'd work great, thing is I want to build it myself (personal development and all!). Can anyone point me in the direction of some good tutorials I could use? Everything I try and Google it just comes up with pre built sliders..

Any resources, or tips and tricks would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!